# Python - why its not sending the value incomingState?

Tags: python, c++, c, arduino

When i execute the python script it connects and do not display any texts back, on other hand the server is always doing this statement only: `if(incomingState != state) { }`

How to make sure python is sending `int` type `incomingState` = `0` or `1` with or without `\n` or `\r\n` ? because the C code is not receiving correctly yet

Any idea please.

python_toserver.py:

```
import serial
import time
#ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=0)
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0' , 9600, timeout=0)
#ser.open()
ser.write('1')

while True:
  data = ser.read(1024)
  if len(data) > 0:
    print 'Got:', data.encode("hex")    
  time.sleep(0.5)
ser.close()
```

**server_c.c:**

```
#define LED1 2

int state = LOW;
char incomingByte = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED1, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

  if (Serial.available() > 0) {

    int incomingState = (Serial.read() == '1');
    Serial.print("I received: ");
    Serial.println(incomingState, DEC);

    if(incomingState != state) { 
      state = incomingState;
      digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH); 
      Serial.print("Setting LED as: ");
      Serial.println(state);
    } else {
      Serial.print("Doing nothing. LED already: ");
      Serial.println(state);
    }

  }

}
```

EDIT: Tried:

py:

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0' , 9600, timeout=0)
#ser.write('\x01')

while True:
  data = ser.read(1024)
  if len(data) > 0:
    #print 'Got:', data.encode("hex")    
    print 'Got: ', data
    ser.write('\x01')
  time.sleep(0.5)
ser.close()
```

c:

```
#define LED1 2

int state = LOW;
char incomingByte = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED1, OUTPUT);
  Serial.print("connected");
}

void loop() {

  if (Serial.available() > 0) {

    int incomingState = (Serial.read() == '1');
    Serial.print("I received: ");
    Serial.println(incomingState, DEC);

    if(incomingState != state) {
      state = incomingState;
      digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH); 
      Serial.print("Setting LED as: ");
      Serial.println(state);
    } else {
      Serial.print("Doing nothing. LED already: ");
      Serial.println(state);
    }

  }

}
```

Then i get reply:

```
Got:  connected
Got:  I received: 0
Doing nothing. LED already: 0

Got:  I received: 0
Doing nothing. LED already: 0

Got:  I received: 0
Doing nothing. LED already: 0

Got:  I received: 0
Doing nothing. LED already: 0

Got:  I received: 0
Doing nothing. LED already: 0

Got:  I received: 0
Doing nothing. LED already: 0

Got:  I received: 0
Doing nothing. LED already: 0
```

Comment: Have you tried sending `\x01`?

Comment: YES -  i sent `\x01` but still it C code is processing `if(incomingState != state) { }` only + in Python i do not see the outputs

Comment: Please see my above EDIT

Comment: I don't understand `c++` much but perhaps you should try receiving without checking for what you received. i.e. just `(char)incomingState = Serial.read()` or something..

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7328183/ - this is working but Python do not exit after receiving the DONE reply how do you exit once the DONE is received?

Comment: Incidentally, you are doing a lot of things in your C++ code that are antiquated C-isms. C++ has a real `bool` type, and constants can be defined just fine with `const` identifiers rather than abusing the preprocessor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you have passed data to the serial port, a single *byte* with a value of 1:

```
ser.write('\x01')
```

But then in the server code, you compare this byte (received as a `char`) to the *ascii character constant* `'1'`, which describes a byte with a value of *49*:

```
int incomingState = (Serial.read() == '1');
```

Comment: WOW - excellent. YES now 1 works. But one problem is that Python is running forever that while loop even C already sent DONE command please see last update code: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7328183/

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7328513/ - this is my last update, if there is any risk in the code please let me know. Beside that its all working thank you.

Comment: When you receive the command, the Python code closes the serial connection, but that does not `break` the `while True:` loop.